# How to smooth/average data that is unevenly distributed?

Tags: r

I have a set of data which come from an experiment.

Due to the way the data was acquired, the acquisition points are very unevenly distributed.

What I need is to compute the mean value of the data set as well as mean values around given x positions.

As I cannot copy my dataset here, please find below a reproducible example of a similar dataset.

First, let's define an evenly distributed data set:

```
set.seed(10)

x <- jitter(seq(0, 3, by = 0.3), factor = 1)
y <- sin(x)^2 + rnorm(length(x), sd = 0.1)

my.df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x, y = sin(x)^2), color = "red")
```

One can see that the loess smoothing function correctly fits the "theoretical" result. If I compute the mean of the data set, I will have a result close to the theoretical mean.

Now, let's add the additional data:

```
x1 <- jitter(seq(0.95, 1.05, length.out = 100), factor = 50)
y1 <- sin(x1)^2 + rnorm(length(x1), sd = 0.1)

my.df1 <- rbind(my.df, data.frame(x = x1, y = y1))
ggplot(my.df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x, y = sin(x)^2), color = "red")
```

You can see now that the loess smoothing is far from the theoretical curve. Moreover, as I have a lot of data around the x = 1 position, the global mean is going to be further from the theoretical curve.

The y value of the smooth at e.g. x = 1.5 is also going to be far away.

Using zoo rollmean function would not solve the problem either. The moving average is indeed computed on n points with close indexes in the data frame, not necessarily close along x.

What I want to do is to compute a trend line, or a moving average that is averaged along x and not the points indexes.

I was thinking about computing the mean on a moving subset of data, e.g. on [0, 0.1], [0.1, 0.2], etc. Is there a function that does that? Or do I have to use something like:

```
mean.values <- c()
for (i in 0:9) {
  print(paste("[", i/10, ", ", (i+1)/10, "]", sep = ""))
  mean.values <- c(mean.values, mean(subset(my.df1, x >= i/10 & x <= (i+1)/10)$y))
}
```

**Edit:** One thing I know about my data, is that for a given x, the y measurements should be "close". The only reason why they would deviate from the theoretical curve is due to acquisition uncertainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct weights and adjust the span like this:

```
my.df1 <- my.df1[order(my.df1$x),]
d <- diff(my.df1$x)
my.df1$w <- c(max(d), d) + c(d, max(d))/2

ggplot(my.df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", aes(weight = w), span = 0.95) +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(x, y = sin(x)^2), color = "red")
```

[image: resulting plot]